# Can't get the logo to move

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to make the logo moving.
I want to have the logo in the nav bar But whatever I try it is stuck in position.
I tried to apply !important, set the top, bottom, but it won't move. does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?
also, the text on the nav bar does not change the colour to black thanks in advance`

```css
.top {
  /*    background-color:4D4D4D;*/
  background-image: url("first-background-2.png");
  object-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  height: 920px;
}

#logo {
  text-align: left !important;
  opacity: 80%;
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px
}

.text {
  padding-right: 20px!important;
  color: black !important;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  word-spacing: 20px;
}

#topnav {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 60;
  opacity: 60%;
  position: relative;
  top: -1150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!docktype html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="edusolut.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Edusolut</title>
  </head>
  <nav id="top bar">
    <div class="top">

    </div>

    <!--    navbar-->

    <div id="topnav">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="./logo2.png" width="auto" height="162 pt" alt="edusolut logo">
      </div>
      <nav class="text">
        <a class="active" href="#top">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">Training</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">Service</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- end navbar-->
```

Comment: Where do you want logo to be where in navbar ?? Whats your expected output ?

Comment: Awsome thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want to move it, you can use the:

margin-left: (amount in pixels)
margin-right: (amount in pixels)

In the CSS box model, the margin is on the outside. So it will definitely move.

If not, you can use:

padding-left: (amount in pixels)
padding-right: (amount in pixels)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text to black with

```
.text > a{
    color:black;
}
```

Please specify where you want the logo to be

Comment: i want to have the logo left in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin/padding or even the positions

```
Paddings;
padding-left: px;
padding-right: px;
padding-top: px;
padding-bottom: px;

Margins;
margin-left: px;
margin-right: px;
margin-top: px;
margin-bottom: px;

create a div form to the logo;
HTML;
<div class="mylogo">
<img src="whatever.png">
</div>

CSS;
.mylogo { //Just a example or you can you the absolute form, if you use that your logo will stay fixed where you put it!
position: relative;
top: px;
left: px;
right: px;
bottom: px;
}
Or text-align, justify-content, etc 
float: left;
text-align: left;
ETC
```